# Hadoop setJarByClass not working

Tags: hadoop

My WordCount example is the following structure:

```
public class WordCount extends Configured implements Tool {

    public static class Map extends
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {}

    public static class Reduce extends
            Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.WARN);
        int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new WordCount(), args);
        System.exit(res);
    }

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

        if (fs.exists(new Path(args[1]))) {
            fs.delete(new Path(args[1]), true);
        }

        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "wordcount");
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
//      job.setJar(WordCount.class.getSimpleName());
        job.waitForCompletion(true);
        System.out.println("Job Finished in "
                + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000.0
                + " seconds");
        return 0;
    }

}
```

The `job.setJarByClass()` call is not working, and I get a "No job jar file set" message. Also, job.getJar() after this call shows "null" value. Anyone knows what's the problem here?

I also tried with `job.setJarByClass(this.getClass())`, `job.setJar("WordCount")` and  `job.setJar(WordCount.class.getSimpleName())`. The first one has no effect, `job.getJar()` returns null, the second and third both give me `FileNotFoundException`: File WordCount does not exist. Then I tried with `job.setJar("src/wordcount/WordCount.java")` and `job.setJar("bin/wordcount/WordCount.class")`, both succeed within eclipse (without this warning message), but still fail with `FileNotFoundException` when executed as standalone jar file on command line. I guess the problem may relate to class path setting if not unresolved dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

think you should add appropriate jar files.

In your case you must have this jar `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job` in your project file.

I imported the following classes and interfaces

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
```

And your project working fine.
Just check after importing all above mentioned classes. If any problem, give me a comment.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more about all the needed dependencies? Currently, I have the following maven dependency entry: hadoop-common,hadoop-mapreduce-client-core,hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient,hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle (all with 2.2.0 version), and my Java version is 1.7.0_25.

Comment: add jar from **hadoop-2.x.x/share/hadoop/common/lib** log4j-1.2.x.jar file. Try this, it may work.

Comment: And all jar from **hadoop-2.x.x/share/hadoop/mapreduce**

Comment: Still get the same msg: WARN  [main] mapreduce.JobSubmitter (JobSubmitter.java:copyAndConfigureFiles(259)) - No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String). And I have tried with parameter this.getClass(), then getJar() still return null

Answer (score 0):

please use this java code for word counting, with two arguments one is input file other one is result file. And add all jar files from `mapreduce` and `common` folders in hadoop directory

```
    package org.samples.mapreduce.training;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;       
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;       
public class WordCount {
 public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }
 } 

 public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) 
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            sum += val.get();
        }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
      conf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "hdfs://localhost:50001");
      conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://localhost:50000");
        Job job = new Job(conf, "wordcount");

    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
 }

}
```

Or If you want use advance version use this code with three arguments, here third one file which you dont want count example `,`

```
package org.samples.mapreduce.training;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Counter;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils;

public class WordCountV2 {

  public static class TokenizerMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    static enum CountersEnum { INPUT_WORDS }

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    private boolean caseSensitive;
    private Set<String> patternsToSkip = new HashSet<String>();

    private Configuration conf;
    private BufferedReader fis;

    @Override
    public void setup(Context context) throws IOException,
        InterruptedException {
      conf = context.getConfiguration();
      caseSensitive = conf.getBoolean("wordcount.case.sensitive", true);
      if (conf.getBoolean("wordcount.skip.patterns", true)) {
        URI[] patternsURIs = Job.getInstance(conf).getCacheFiles();
        for (URI patternsURI : patternsURIs) {
          Path patternsPath = new Path(patternsURI.getPath());
          String patternsFileName = patternsPath.getName().toString();
          parseSkipFile(patternsFileName);
        }
      }
    }

    private void parseSkipFile(String fileName) {
      try {
        fis = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String pattern = null;
        while ((pattern = fis.readLine()) != null) {
          patternsToSkip.add(pattern);
        }
      } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println("Caught exception while parsing the cached file '"
            + StringUtils.stringifyException(ioe));
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      String line = (caseSensitive) ?
          value.toString() : value.toString().toLowerCase();
      for (String pattern : patternsToSkip) {
        line = line.replaceAll(pattern, "");
      }
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(line);
      while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);
        Counter counter = context.getCounter(CountersEnum.class.getName(),
            CountersEnum.INPUT_WORDS.toString());
        counter.increment(1);
      }
    }
  }

  public static class IntSumReducer
       extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int sum = 0;
      for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
      }
      result.set(sum);
      context.write(key, result);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    GenericOptionsParser optionParser = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args);
    String[] remainingArgs = optionParser.getRemainingArgs();
    if (!(remainingArgs.length != 2 || remainingArgs.length != 4)) {
      System.err.println("Usage: wordcount <in> <out> [-skip skipPatternFile]");
      System.exit(2);
    }
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCountV2.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    List<String> otherArgs = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0; i < remainingArgs.length; ++i) {
      if ("-skip".equals(remainingArgs[i])) {
        job.addCacheFile(new Path(remainingArgs[++i]).toUri());
        job.getConfiguration().setBoolean("wordcount.skip.patterns", true);
      } else {
        otherArgs.add(remainingArgs[i]);
      }
    }
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs.get(0)));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs.get(1)));

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Added all jars under commons and mapreduce directory, version-1 still have this annoying warn msg, it can finish within eclipse, but it will terminate with "ClassNotFoundException" when exported as executable jar. version-2 got a NullPointException at line 49.

Comment: I think you didn't set **job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);** and make sure that your class name must set in place of **WordCount.class**... and i run jar file its working perfectly, edit appropriate parameters and values.Example:**conf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "hdfs://localhost:50001");** here you have set different port number, just check this kind of values and parameters.